# Laravel : How return nested JSON from models

Tags: php, laravel, nested-lists

I have an app contain many tables :
products table , order table , order_items table.
I made models for all of them as below :

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_name',
        'category_id',
        'price',
        'sale',
        'counter',
        'isfavore'
    ];
    public function Order_item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order_item');
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category' ,'category_id');
    }
}
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'status',
    ];

    public function order_item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order_item');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User' ,'user_id');
    }
}
class Order_item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'order_id',
        'product_id',
        'quantity',
    ];
    
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order' ,'order_id');
    }
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product' ,'product_id');
    }
}
```

I want to display details like below depend on order_id :

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "user_id": 23,
    "status": "ordered",
    "order_item": [
        {
            "id": 30,
            "order_id": 7,
            "product_id": 5,
            "quantity": 1,
            "product_name" : "banana",   //-----------------------want to add from product model
            "price" : "2000"             //-----------------------want to add from product model
        },
        {
            "id": 31,
            "order_id": 7,
            "product_id": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "product_name" : "apple",
            "price" : "1500"
        }
    ]
}
```

I create this controller which show same result above without product name and price:

```
public function get_order($id){
        $order=Order::find($id);
        $order->order_item;
        return $order;
    }
```

### Now just I need to add product name and price from product model ,How can I do that?

Comment: You have to use with for this and call product relation under

Comment: Line "$order->order_item;" in your controller does literally nothing.

Comment: `Order::with('order_item.product')->find($id)` this will fetch product as array withthin order_items.

Comment: @KarolDabrowski $order->order_item is add nested array thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the relationships.
Try this:

```
   public function get_order($id){
            $order=Order::find($id);
            $order_items = Order_item::with('product')->where('order_id',$id)->get();
            return $order;
        }
```

Comment: thank you it solved just by change :  $order=Order::with('order_item.product')->find($id)

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_name',
        'category_id',
        'price',
        'sale',
        'counter',
        'isfavore'
    ];
    public function Order_item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order_item');
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category' ,'category_id');
    }
}
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'status',
    ];

    public function order_item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order_item');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User' ,'user_id');
    }
}
class Order_item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'order_id',
        'product_id',
        'quantity',
    ];
    
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order' ,'order_id');
    }
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product' ,'product_id');
    }
}
```

--- CONTROLLER ---

```
public function get_order($id){
    $order=Order::with('order_item.product')->where('id',$id)->first();
}
```

---- RESPONSE ----

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "user_id": 23,
    "status": "ordered",
    "order_item": [
        {
            "id": 30,
            "order_id": 7,
            "product_id": 5,
            "quantity": 1,
            "product" : {
                "product_name" : "banana",  
                "price" : "2000"            
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 31,
            "order_id": 7,
            "product_id": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "product" : {
                "product_name" : "banana",  
                "price" : "2000"            
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you it solved just by change :  $order=Order::with('order_item.product')->find($id)

Comment: Can you maybe add a little explanation of what was wrong with OPs code and what you changed to make it work? Thx

Comment: @Developer the where condition in `whereHas` is useless in get_order function of controller section.

Comment: @danish-khan-I thanks for correcting i changed my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I get best answer from @Develope and @danish-khan-I ,just change controller to :

```
public function get_order($id){
        $order=Order::with('order_item.product')->find($id);
        return $order;
    }
```